# What's the definition of column/row rank of a matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

In my textbook(Friedberg):

1. The rank of linear transformation is defined to be the dimension of its range.
2. The rank of a matrix $A$ is defined to be the rank of the corresponding linear transformation $L_A$ from $A$.

So, what is the definition of the rank of the "row rank"/"column rank" of $A$? I've seen so many usage of these words on this site, it's not clear and seems to be abused.

Comment: Given an $m \times n$ matrix, we can think of its rows as vectors in $n$-dimensional space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$), and its columns as vectors in $m$-dimensional space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^m$). So the span of the rows is a subspace of $n$-space, and the row rank is the dimension of this subspace. Similarly, the span of the columns is a subspace of $m$-space, and the column rank is the dimension of this subspace. Often we simply say "rank" because it is a theorem that row rank equals column rank, so really there is only one number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the dimension of the row (resp. column) space.  That space is the span of the rows (resp. columns).

Comment: Isn't that *rank* related to *range*, it looks like just *dimension* here?

Comment: Well, a useful fact is that the range is the column space.

Comment: I mean given a linear transformation, then we define *range* and thus we have *rank*. Isn't that when you said "range is the column space" you implicitly mean $A$ is a linear transformation?

Comment: Yes.  We are talking about linear transformations.

Comment: So row rank of $A$ implicitly takes $A^T$, not $A$, as the underlying linear transformation? Since range can only formed by columns.

Comment: Well, the rows constitute a set of vectors.  You don't really need to get into that.  Interestingly though, the row rank always equals the column rank.  Thus we can just speak of the rank of the matrix.

Comment: Indeed, though, the row space will be the image of the transpose.

Comment: "the range is the column space" so "the range is not row space", so you cannot define row rank for $A$, but $A^T$, the same conclusion of your last comment.

Comment: Remember, there is a subtle difference between the matrix and the linear transformation.  The matrix represents the linear transformation relative to a basis.  Change the basis, and the matrix changes.

Comment: True your definition above doesn't give a way to do row rank.  But this is just the number of linearly independent rows, just as with the columns.